# Which is the correct way of allocating shared memory statically in cuda and why?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Out of the following two ways of allocating shared memory statically, which method is correct and why? I get same results for both but I am  trying to understand the behavior in a little more detail.

Kernel 1:

```
__shared__ int as[3][3],bs[3][3];
__global__ void Sharesum(int* a,int* b,int* c,int n)
{
    int s,k,i,sum=0;
    int tx,ty,bx,by;
    tx=threadIdx.x;
    ty=threadIdx.y;
    as[ty][tx]=a[tx+n*ty];
    bs[ty][tx]=b[tx+n*ty];
    sum += as[ty][tx]+bs[ty][tx];
    c[tx*n+ty]=sum;
}
```

kernel 2:

```
    __global__ void Sharesum(int* a,int* b,int* c,int n)
{
    __shared__ int as[3][3],bs[3][3];

    int s,k,i,sum=0;
    int tx,ty,bx,by;
    tx=threadIdx.x;
    ty=threadIdx.y;
    as[ty][tx]=a[tx+n*ty];
    bs[ty][tx]=b[tx+n*ty];
    sum += as[ty][tx]+bs[ty][tx];
    c[tx*n+ty]=sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any difference between these two methods *for what you have shown*. I'm not sure there is an answer that suggests that one is "correct" and one isn't.

However, the first one, which we could call a "global scope" declaration, affects *all kernels* defined in the module.  That means all kernels will reserve and have available shared allocations according to the global definition.

The second one only affects the kernel it is scoped to.

Either one or both could be correct, depending on your desired intent.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In case of global declaration  will  it not change the scope of the shared memory from block to grid ? So all the threads in the grid will see the same shared memory?

Comment: No. shared memory is always a logical block scope allocation.  There is no possibility or opportunity to have all the threads in the grid see "the same" shared memory.  Each threadblock gets its own copy of shared memory, always.  Only global memory has grid-wide global visibility.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor understanding, what do we mean by " a logical block scope allocation."

Comment: It means that the items written to shared memory by block A, will not be visible in the shared memory available to block B, for any two distinct blocks A and B in the grid.